# PHP get the id of the last data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am new to php language and i want to add the id of the last data in the database as an int to a variable.
can you help me how can i do this

here are some of my attempts:

```php
$lastID = mysqli_query("SELECT * from posts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 1");

$lastID++;
```

```php
$lastID = mysqli_query("SELECT * from posts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 1");
$lastid = (int)$lastID;
$lastid++;
```

Comment: Use [mysqli_insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) to get the last inserted id, if it's during the same connection. It won't work if the record was inserted during a different connection though (like in a previous request). It's also good to remember that selecting the last inserted id like this could give you a race condition, depending on what you're planning on doing with the id.

Comment: You have to FETCH a result from the resultset. It does not get delivered as a return from a `mysql_query()` [Hundereds of examples in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Hi @MagnusEriksson I dont think that is what the OP is asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you've connected to the mysql server:

```
$db_handle = mysqli_connect($db_server_name, $db_user_name, $db_password);
```

Select the database you want to work with:

```
mysqli_select_db($db_handle,$database_name);
```

write your query. The following query will get you the largest post_id number:

```
$query = "SELECT post_id FROM posts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

query mysql:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_handle, $query);
```

Fetch your data as a row array from the query result:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

put the value of 'post_id' from the row array into a variable:

```
$lastid = $row['post_id'];
```

Comment: You should really use the 4 parameter `connect with param 4 being the database name, then you dont need the select db

Answer (score 2):

First of all, use this query.

```
SELECT MAX(post_id) post_id FROM posts
```

It's more efficient than the query in your example, especially if `post_id` is the primary key.

Second, do this.

```php
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT MAX(post_id) post_id FROM posts");
if (!$result) { 
   /* the query failed, report an error */
} else {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
    $lastID = $row->post_id;
    $lastID += 1;
}
```

Third, **beware a possible race condition.** If another instance of a program inserts something into the table between the time you fetch the MAX(post_id) and the time you use the incremented value, the incremented value may be wrong. This kind of problem is *very* hard to detect when testing because you have to get the concurrency just right. But it *will* come up in production when your application is busy.

Comment: But you also missed out the FETCH?

Comment: it works too but i got an error  ( Undefined property: mysqli_result::$post_id ) (it could be from me) but it works

Comment: @RiggsFolly blush you're right. I fixed it.

Comment: :) :) :) Well thanks for the humourous comment, made I giggle

Comment: Yeah, it's all fun and games until somebody hits the race condition. :-)